# How to select distinct records on the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I execute the following query in SQL Server CORRECTLY!!

ON running this query

```
select distinct * from dbo.TableA
```

It gives me wrong results. It shows me duplicated records as well

Sorry guys, I might be asking a very easy question.. but I googled a lot but didnt get any fruitful result...

Answer (score 3):

It didn't give you duplicate records - there will be some value on each of those "duplicates" that is different to the equivalent values on the other records.

If you only want to see distinct combinations values of specific columns, explicitly specify those columns in your query - eg:

```
select distinct columnA, columnB, columnC from dbo.TableA
```

Comment: Here's my example
Table A
`a 1 1`
`a 1 1`
`b 1 2`

select distinct * will give me all the result as :: 

`a 1 1`
`a 1 1`
`b 1 2`

It really should give as 

`a 1 1`
`b 1 2`

Comment: @Matthew: See my updated answer - if you only select those three specific columns, you will only get `a 1 1` `b 1 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name(s) FROM table_name
```

Comment: What if I dont want to mention the column names ? Because there are 300 columns in my table

Answer (score 0):

If there is no primary key field then your query returns distinct records only, otherwise you need to use like:

```
select distinct column_name from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to get suplicate rows using DISTINCT, because that's it's sole function: to remove duplicates. Keep in mind that if you have a PK on your table, then all your rows will be different. If you DON'T have a PK (which doesn't sound right), then perhaps you have a datetime field and are only seing the date but not the time?